# How do I parse out both single line and multiline in regex?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I need to parse out both the single line data and multiline data. How can I do this using only one regex?

```
-------------------------------------------
/ Vegetation /
-------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Shrubs [-] = Number of shrubs
-- Shrub_x [m/rad] = The position of shrub nr x in either (x,y,z) or in (latitude, longitude, h)
--          (XY/WGS84, height above msl)
-- 
------------------------------------------
I.Shrubs := 3; -- {MIN:0 MAX:10}
Car.Shrub_1 := (0.0, 0.0, 1.5);
Car.Shrub_2 := (3.4, 10.0, 0.2);
Car.Shrub_3 := (5.0, 5.0, 2.0);

-------------------------------------------
/ Lawn /
-------------------------------------------
-- Some general info thats not required but that could be written here.
-- 
-- Lawn_Attitude [rad] = The attitude of the lawn as Euler angles. 
--                North, East and Up is used as reference frame.
-- Lawn_Quality [-] = The quality index of the lawn.
--
-------------------------------------------
Eul.Lawn_Attitude := (0.7853981,-0.23651236, 0.017); 
I.Lawn_Quality := 5; --{0,1,2,3,4,5}
```

right now I am using:

```
-- \w+ \[.+\n(?!--[ \t]{2,}) # for single line and
-- [^ \t\n].+\n--\s{3,}.+ # for multi line.
```

I need to take into consideration that the data may be written using both tabs and spaces because the user might use either and some IDEs consider tabs to be 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match `--` followed by a space and then a non whitespace char and the rest of the line.

Then match all following lines that start with `--` and at least 3 whitespace chars.

Note that `\s` could also match a newline.

```
^-- \S.*(?:\n--\s{3}.*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q8EHuz/1)

If there has to be an opening square bracket in the start of both lines, and you want to match 3 whitespace chars without a newline:

```
^-- [^][\n]*\[.*(?:\n--[^\S\n]{3}.*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RHMmtI/1)

Comment: That works, but I forgot to include some of the other data that messes with that regex, sorry.

Comment: @EddieMossberg Does the second pattern work out? I have updated both patterns appending an anchor `^`

Comment: Almost, there is a part with loads of spaces before the text as the second row, but it gets all the other ones. The one that is not working is 2 tabs and 10 spaces long. (I'm not the one who makes the in data)

Comment: @EddieMossberg Can you add that example to the question?

Comment: @EddieMossberg So now these are the matches https://regex101.com/r/kfahfi/1 should there be less?

Comment: Now StackOverflow is one of the problems I was talking about, it changed the long amount of spaces from tabs and spaces to just spaces. So it works with just spaces, but use 2 tabs in the beginning in lawn_Attitude and it does not work.

Comment: @EddieMossberg Ah, there is a space in the pattern. LIke this? https://regex101.com/r/RHMmtI/1